# iOS 10 Save to Camera Roll Bug/Crash

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios10

When trying to save an image to camera roll in iOS10 using

`UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);`

the app crashes without any information. Same exact method does not cause crash on iOS 9 devices

Comment: Please mark which answer solves the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add Below permission in Info.plist

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to the camera to take photos.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to photos.</string>
```

More info [Click here](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/09/infoplist-privacy-settings-in-ios-10.html)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Edit you Info.plist

[image: Info.plist]

You need to add these line in the plist.

It will crash too if you're using camera. In case of this, I put the solutions here.

If you're using camera, you just need to add the first line.

If you're just using saving photo to local album, you only need to add the second line.

You can change the description to what you wanna claim. It shows in iOS Camera/Photo alertView to get user's permissoin.

Answer (score 0):

This was kind of a sneaky update (I didn't hear about this at least), but for iOS10 there are new required Info.plist files for requiring access to assets such as `Photos` (which causes the crash in this case). Take a read here

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/privacy-settings-in-ios-10/

But for solving this specific problem, just this to your Info.plist source code:

`<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Reason why you need the permissions here</string>`

Comment: Looks like in iOS11 (or there about) they also added a NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription (notice the Add part) requirement to save to the library (what OP was trying to do).